# how to configure apache2 to host multiple website on XP?

Tags: apache2

I want to configure apache2 to host multiple websites on XP. Not very sure with editing the httpd.conf file. Can anyone help with the configuration part?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page regarding setting up virtual hosts: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only host one site with XP.

But if you can host more here is the code to put in the bottom of your `httpd.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost my.ip.addr.ess

<VirtualHost my.ip.addr.ess>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerPath /domain
DocumentRoot /htdocs/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Original from Apache site

```
NameVirtualHost 111.22.33.44

<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerPath /domain
DocumentRoot /web/domain
</VirtualHost>
```